# Unit Testing failures from Futures in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, future

I'm trying to test the error handling in a script I'm writing. If the async function fetchBar fails I pattern match the failure case and then return a successful future containing the failed result.

```
val fetchedBar = Try(fooClient.fetchBar(params))

fetchedBar match {
  case Success(bar) => foobar(bar)
  case Failure(e) => Future.successful(FooResult(success = false))
}
```

However when I unit test this flow I'm having trouble testing the failure case. I have stubbed fetchBar to return a failed future as shown below.

```
val fetchedBar = Try(Future.failed(new Exception()))
```

But I noticed that fetchedBar returns a Success rather than a Failure. Why is that and how can I stub the fetchBar function to create a failed Try?

Comment: A `Try[Future[T]]` doesn't make much sense, special because a **Future** already catch failures. I would recommend you to take a look to the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're slightly mixing concepts - but that's not 100% your fault.

The thing is, `Future` in Scala is a bit non-orthogonal concept - that it is, it represents not only the notion of delayed execution, but also a notion of failure.

Because of this, in most cases it doesn't make much sense to wrap the Future into the Try, or vice versa - unless one wants to explicitly separate the notion of failure from the notion of asynchrony.

In other words, the following combinations are sort of weird, but still has their use:

1. `Try[Future[_]]` - future already captures failures. However, makes sense if you have a (bad-behaving) library method that normally returns a Future, but may throw on a "synchronous" path:

```
def futureReciprocal(i: Int): Float = { 
   val reciprocal = 1 / i // Division by zero is intentional
   Future.successful(reciprocal)
}

futureReciprocal(0) // throws
Try(futureReciprocal(0)) // Failure(DivisionByZero(...))
```

... but this is basically a workaround to fix poorly implemented function

2. `Future[Try[_]]` - sometimes useful to separate the "business" error (represented by `Future.success(Failure(...))`) from "infrastructure" failure (represented by `Future.failed(...)`). On a side - this is especially useful with akka-streams, which tend to treat failed futures as "fatal" to the stream.

In your case, what you want to do is to assert on the *result* of the future. To do so, you have at least two options, actually.

1. Block till the future is completed and check the outcome - this is usually done with `scala.concurrent.Await`:

```
// writing this without the compiler, might mix up namespaces a bit
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

val future = fooClient.fetchBar(...)
val futureResult: Try[_] = Await.result(future, 1.second)
futureResult match { case Success(_) => ??? ; case Failure(exc) => ???; }
```

2. Use some test framework that supports working with futures - e.g. scalatest:

```
class YourTest extends FlatSpec with ScalaFutures {
   "fetchBar should return failed future" in {
        val future: Future[XYZ] = fooClient.fetchBar(...)
        // whenReady comes from the ScalaFutures trait
        whenReady(future) { result => result shouldBe XYZ } // asserting on the successful future result
        whenReady(future.failed) { exc => exc shoulBe a[RuntimeException] } // asserting on an exception in the failed future
   }
}
```